# Upload json (or csv) document to Azure Data Factory and create graph in Cosmos DB

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use the Azure Data Factory to move a json or csv file from my blob storage to my Cosmos DB graph database.

By formatting the json file correctly, I am able to upload vertices, but have no idea how to create edges. Hard coding the edges into the json file does not work. This is one of the vertices in my json file:

```
{
"id": "o0001",
"label": "Order",
"type": "vertex",
"Product2": 1.0,
"Product3": 1.0,
"Product4": 1.0,
"Product5": 1.0,
"Product6": 1.0,
"Product7": 1.0,
"Product8": 1.0,
"Product24": 1.0,
"Product25": 1.0,
"Product26": 1.0,
"Product27": 1.0
}
```

And this is an edge:

```
{
"label": "purchased",
"type": "edge",
"inVLabel": "Product",
"outVLabel": "Order",
"inV": "Product2",
"outV": "o0001"
}
```

Everything gets imported as a vertex. Does anybody have an idea how to upload both vertices and edges?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert you json to dataframe and then execute the below steps to add records in Cosmos DB with one row in the DataFrame equating to 1 vertex in Cosmos.

- Click on the below link and download option and select the `uber.jar https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11/1.2.2/jar` then add in your dependency.

  spark-shell --master yarn --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 10g --num-executors 10 --driver-memory 10g --jars "path/to/jar/dependency/azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.3.0_2.11-1.2.2-uber.jar" --packages "com.google.guava:guava:18.0,com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1,com.microsoft.azure:azure-documentdb:1.16.1"
- here is the code for the same:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

  val data = Seq(
  Row(2, "Abb"),
  Row(4, "Bcc"),
  Row(6, "Cdd")
  )

  val schema = List(
  StructField("partitionKey", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("name", StringType, true)
  )

  val DF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  StructType(schema)
  )

  val writeConfig = Map("Endpoint" -> "https://*******.documents.azure.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" -> "**************",
  "Database" -> "db_name",
  "Collection" -> "collection_name",
  "Upsert" -> "true",
  "query_pagesize" -> "100000",
  "bulkimport"-> "true",
  "WritingBatchSize"-> "1000",
  "ConnectionMaxPoolSize"-> "100",
  "partitionkeydefinition"-> "/partitionKey")

  DF.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("overwrite").options(writeConfig).save()
  ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately, I didn't understand much ^^' I just want to connect my vertices, that is all. I already know how to import the json as vertices. My problem is that I cannot create edges.